# Appended div isn't part of the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `<div>`; it contains a `<span>`.  When you click on the `<div>`, it removes the span, and replaces it with a `<div>` containing an `<input>` and a `<button>`.  This is all well and good.

The `<button>`, when clicked is supposed to remove its parent `<div>` (the appended one) and replace it with a `<span>` again, but something is wrong.  It seems that the parent `<div>` isn't a part of the DOM!

Anyway, here's a quick example:

```
<div id="myPage">
    <div id="clickMe" class="selectedField editMe">
        <span>Click Me</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Some HTML, nothing too fancy.  Though, since the DOM is gonna keep changing, I used `.on` to delegate the events.  Here's the JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
    $('#myPage').on('click', '.selectedField', function () {
        if($(this).hasClass('editMe')){
            var $this = $(this).toggleClass('editMe editing'),
                $input = $('<input/>', {
                    placeholder: 'type something...'
                }),
                $cancel = $('<button></button>', {
                    class: 'cancel',
                    type: 'button',
                    html: 'x'
                })

            $this.children('span').replaceWith($('<div></div>').append($input, $cancel));
        }
    });

    $('#myPage').on('click', '.selectedField .cancel', function () {
        var $this = $(this).closest('.selectedField').toggleClass('editMe editing');

        console.log($this.children('div')[0]);

        $this.children('div').replaceWith('<span>Click Me</span>');
    });
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Z8abW/

This looks simple enough, right?  Clicking the box replaces the `<span>` with a `<div>`, then clicking the (newly added) `<button>` puts the `<span>` back.

But, this doesn't work.  The first event works.  I can click to add the `<input>` and the `<button>`, but clicking the `<button>` does not work.

I don't know how to explain it, but it seems the `<div>` I want to remove isn't part of the DOM!  When I click on the `<button>`, nothing happens on the page.  I added a `console.log` to make sure the event was being ran.  Sure enough, it was, but something was odd.

I'm using Chrome 27, and its console has a neat feature.  If you `console.log` DOM elements, you can hover over them in the log and it will highlight them in the page.  I did `console.log($this[0])`, and it highlighted the element, like I would expect.  But, when I did `console.log($this.children('div')[0]);`, the element was *not* highlighted in the page!  Why not?  Makes me think the element, for some reason, isn't in the DOM.  It does log a `<div>` to the console, but it doesn't seem to be the one in the actual DOM.

Because of this the `$this.children('div').replaceWith` line doesn't do anything!

What's going on!  Why can I replace the `<span>` with a `<div>`, but not the other way around?

Comment: You need to stopPropagation on your second handler, because it causes a loop: Event is propaged to your first handler and as you toggled class editMe, it run through it, and recreate the input/button

Comment: Or just `return false;` in every button, link, label etc. event.

Comment: @RobinLeboeuf: Oh wow, you're right!  I didn't even think of that.  Thanks! :-D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Propagation issues. Change:

```
$('#myPage').on('click', '.selectedField .cancel', function () {
```

to

```
$('#myPage').on('click', '.selectedField .cancel', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Z8abW/5/)**

The click on the cancel bubbles up and triggers the click event on the parent. Kill it with fire.

Comment: But in the parent event, I check for the `editMe` class.... which is being added back in the `.cancel` event.  Thanks!  I didn't realize the event was bubbling up back to the parent, which would add the `<input>` again.

Comment: I like return false at the end more for this situation(s). +1

Answer (score 6):

Update `$('#myPage').on('click', '.selectedField .cancel', function ()` to

```
$('#myPage .selectedField ').on('click', '.cancel', function ()
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8abW/1/)

Comment: I guess the live listeners do not get updated when it sees `.selectedField` has not changed.